# With Jinja2 and Babel, how do I translate sentences containing HTML tags?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-babel

Suppose I have a Jinja2 template, and I'm using Flask-Babel to translate my project. For example:

```
<p>The <em>best</em> way of using the Internet is
to use <a href="{{ url_for('our_site') }}">our site</a>.</p>
```

So I have a sentence with a link and an emphasis. Suppose I then want to translate my sentence. The obvious way would be to use `gettext()` or the `{% trans %}` tag:

```
<p>{% trans %}The {% endtrans %} <em>{% trans %}best{% endtrans %}</em>
{% trans %}way of using the Internet is to use{% endtrans %}
<a href="{{ url_for('our_site') }}">{% trans %}our site{% endtrans %}</a>{% trans %}.{% endtrans %}</p>
```

Obviously the problem is that this breaks up the sentence into multiple fragments that don't translate well. This would result in the translator considering the string "The", "best", "way of using the Internet is to use", and "our site" as all separate strings, plus the punctuation. Of course, the translator will want to restructure the sentence, and choose what words to link and emphasize separately.

So in light of that, what's the solution? How do I have a sentence with tags in it that translates as one unit?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jinja2 or Babel, but this seems more like a logical conundrum than an implementation specific one, so I'll take a shot anyway : Why not just write a script that makes sure any html tags inside the text gets ignored by the translator during interpretation? In this example, you could segment anything inside the <p> tag as a single unit. This gets read by the translator but the <a> and <em> tags *inside* it get ignored and what's left is the original text.

Comment: Well, I don't want the tags to get ignored, I want the human translator to re-arrange them based on the translation. But that gets complicated, because then I'd have to tell Jinja2 to trust what comes out of translation as code and not to escape it, which would be problematic for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Put another way, I want the placement of the HTML tags to be something the translator decides, so dropping/ignoring them won't work.

Comment: If what you're saying is that the tags that existed in the original text need to be on their *equivalent position* post translation, then I'm afraid I can't think of anything short of using a grammar sensitive parser that intelligently identifies and categorizes parts of your text across languages. Maybe using something like https://spacy.io/  
Or this demo : https://foxtype.com/sentence-tree

Comment: Seems a bit like overkill. I guess what I'm hoping for is something like _('Hello there, *Joe*'), such that there's a neutral formatting choice that just carries over into translations.

Comment: It's a bit overkill because so is what you're trying to do. I think you're underestimating how complicated your easy example actually is. Keeping proper nouns aside, some words don't even have an equivalent in other languages, and when they do, they can be a part of another compound/helping word, or split into different words placed apart in the sentence. Your solution would have to have to somehow account for all that while intuitively understanding the grammar for both languages to prevent the formatting from being butchered by context. There's a lot to formatting just being *carried over*.

Comment: also looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the gettext() and the safe filter

```
{{ gettext('The <em>best</em> solution') | safe }}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters

Your translator would then be able to arrange the tags.

If you want to keep things a little simpler for the translator you could add a custom markdown filter and use that that add simple formatting within phrases, see here for an example https://gist.github.com/glombard/7554134

Answer (score 3):

You can do that:

```
{% trans url=url_for('our_site') %}
<p>The <em>best</em> way of using the Internet is to use <a href="{{ url }}">our site</a>.</p>
{% endtrans %}
```

same with object nested variables (`obj.site_name`):

```
{% trans url=url_for('our_site'), site_name=obj.site_name %}
<p>The <em>best</em> way of using the Internet is
to use <a href="{{ url }}">our site</a>{{ site_name }}.</p>
{% endtrans %}
```

so you have to declare variables as the `trans` function params, otherwise `trans` won't work. To read more, please visit [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#i18n).